# Issues with installing "rgdal" on R 4.1.3

Tags: r, installation, package, rgdal

I have had issues trying to install the package "rgdal" over the past three weeks. I've talked with IT at my university for help. Most recently, IT suggested I uninstall "sf", install "rgdal," and then install "sf" again, but I still haven't been able to install "rgdal."

I should add I use a Mac, so I'm probably running R on a MacOS system.

I have entered this in the extra modules tool when I set up a new session: `gdal/3.4.3-gcc/9.5.0 proj/7.2.1-gcc/9.5.0 geos/3.9.1-gcc/9.5.0 sqlite/3.38.5-gcc/9.5.0.`

Then, I start a new R session. Once in, I write `install.packages("rgdal")`.

I got a different message before I uninstalled "sf", but this is the message I get now:

```
> install.packages("rgdal")
Installing package into ‘/home/laner/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘sp’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sp_1.6-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1031688 bytes (1007 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1007 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgdal_1.6-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4465310 bytes (4.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.3 MB

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/laner/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/laner/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-sp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sp’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘sp’ is not available for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/laner/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/local_scratch/pbs.439178.pbs02/tmp.cVaR7q1tOU/RtmpxrMJ81/downloaded_packages’
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue; this attempt did not work for me:
`install.packages("rgdal", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")`

I solved it by downloading [rgdal](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/rgdal_1.6-7.zip)
and then installing from the Package Archive file (.zip) rather than the CRAN repository which continuously failed due to 60 sec timeout on R 4.1.3.

Console results:

````
Please note that rgdal will be retired during October 2023,
plan transition to sf/stars/terra functions using GDAL and PROJ
at your earliest convenience.
See https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html and https://github.com/r-spatial/evolution
rgdal: version: 1.6-7, (SVN revision 1203)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.6.2, released 2023/01/02
Path to GDAL shared files: C:/R-Project/library/rgdal/gdal
GDAL does not use iconv for recoding strings.
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 9.2.0, March 1st, 2023, [PJ_VERSION: 920]
Path to PROJ shared files: C:/R-Project/library/rgdal/proj
PROJ CDN enabled: FALSE
Linking to sp version:2.0-0
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading sp or rgdal.```
````